# Throttle with dispatch

Tags: react-redux, lodash, store, throttling, debouncing

I have an event listener that dispatches an action.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    store.dispatch(screenResize());
})
```

I am trying to throttle (or debounce) this with lodash

The question is, should I do

```
const throttledScreenResize =  _.throttle(screenResize(), 250)

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    store.dispatch(throttledScreenResize);
})
```

or

```
const throttledScreenResize =  _.throttle(() => store.dispatch(screenResize()), 250)

window.addEventListener('resize', throttledScreenResize)
```

or neither? Then what?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try either of these?

Comment: @UtsavPatel no, I didn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Take the 2nd approach**:

Call the `store.dispatch(..)` inside the `_throttle`. This will make sure that the `store.dispatch` is executed not more than once every 250 ms

```js
const throttledScreenResize =  _.throttle(() => store.dispatch(screenResize()), 250)

window.addEventListener('resize', throttledScreenResize)
```

**In the 1st approach:**  `store.dispatch` is called on every `resize` event.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it would be like that, but wanted to make sure